# Add a "Done" button to dismiss a programmatically created UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I'm a swift newbie and made a demo app which has a UIViewController and UITableViewController in the Storyboard. The UIViewController has a Collection View and an embedded navigation controller. On tapping a collection view cell, the app segues to the UITableViewController. I can come back to my UIViewController from the UITableViewController as well. All this works well. Now, some of the rows in my UITableViewController have URLs. On tapping a URL, I programmatically create a webview inside a UIviewcontroller and get the URL to load in it. The issue is that I can't dismiss the webview and get back to my UITableViewController after this. This is the code I have in my UITableViewController  class :

```
// When user taps a row, get the URL and load it in a webview
let mywebViewController = UIViewController()
let webView = UIWebView(frame: mywebViewController.view.bounds)
webView.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: url)) // url from the row a user taps
mywebViewController.view = webView
self.navigationController!.presentViewController(mywebViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

How can I add a Done button to this programmatically created UIviewcontroller to dismiss the webview and get back to my UITableViewController

Answer (score 37):

You can wrap the `mywebViewController` in a `UINavigationController` then set the `rightBarButtonItem` to `UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .Done, target: self, action: "dismiss")` like this:

```
let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: mywebViewController)
mywebViewController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .Done, target: self, action: "dismiss")

self.navigationController!.presentViewController(navController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

and add a `dismiss` function in your `UITableViewController`:

```
func dismiss() {
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Rather helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Add done button to your presented ViewController and make an action for it.
To dismiss ViewController try this :

```
self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

Add button in `mywebViewController` and in its `@IBAction`, call

```
self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do one thing.

As you are pushing your `mywebViewController` into the navigation controller, make the navigation bar visible.

By simply tapping on Back button in the navigation bar you can easily dismiss your `mywebViewController`.

Hope this helps you. :)

Comment: `code: self.navigationController!.pushViewController(mywebViewController, animated: true) ` allows me to come back to the UITableViewController from the webview. But I want to test using "presentViewController"

Comment: then in that case you need to add a button to the navigation bar and do self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil) in the button's action.

Answer (score -1):

Update for Swift 4 & 5

In the VC you're navigating from

```
navController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: .done, target: self, action: #selector(self.dismiss))
```

Have to declare your selector as an @objc func

```
@objc func dismiss(){
        self.dismiss(animated: true)
    }
```

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted, I used this approach today... maybe because the selector will get you a "Ambiguous use of 'dismiss'"... which I fixed by simply using `@objc func dismiss(){`